# 404 error: Page not found. (Magento 2 fresh installation ubuntu 18)

Tags: magento, magento2

I made **fresh installation of magento 2.3 on ubuntu 18**. I have imported existing database that I have already used in that project in previous installation. Now I am getting **error 404 for homepage, admin and all related urls in that project**.

[image: 404 error magento]

I have fixed paths in core_config_data table but it didnt helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem.

If someone encounter the same problem, the key is to enable rewrite mode in apache.

Execute next commands:

> **sudo a2enmod rewrite**
>
> **sudo systemctl restart apache2**